# cURL C++ send accented chars

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to send this string "ààà" via curl POST HTTP.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
char* content = "value=ààà!";
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:3000");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);                                                                                          
    if (res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

I tried to send wchat_t* (using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, wcslen(content)`)
instead of char*, I didn't solved.

I even tried to send using content-type:application/json but I get `Unexpected end of JSON input` .

Comment: You need to check how your source file has been encoded.  Or you could read the text from a file that has known encoding.

Comment: if your'e on vs2017 you can put a `u8` in front of that string literal to ensure it's encoded in UTF-8 in the binary

Comment: What is the problem you have?